# Can I make firebase file URLs publicly available without requiring token?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am using firebase to allow users to upload their files to the Storage buckets. I was using the getDownLoadURL() to fetch the publicly available URL...however, this comes with an embedded token to allow access to the file.

In my same app, I'm using the Google Document viewer which takes a URL to preview the doc. Unfortunately, the Google Doc Viewer does not work with the firebase URLs's with the embedded token.

In Google Console, on an individual file, I click to make it public. In that case, the URL is now reachable via the https://storage.googleapis.com// format...and I don't need to use the token which works great.

So, what I want to do is mark/make a file public when I'm uploading it to firebase. I have reviewed the firebase docs and there doesn't seem to be a makePublic() method like there is on the Google API's.

Is there a way I can mark a file as public during upload, so that it can be accessed without any token?

The other solution was that I could update the bucket to be accessible, but this makes it totally open to be browsed at https://storage.googleapis.com/, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The client-side Firebase APIs don't know anything about the underlying Google Cloud Platform configurations for public content in storage buckets.  So that won't be an option.

You will have to involve some backend code to change the object's configuration after it's uploaded.  You could set up your own API endpoint via Cloud Functions (or whatever backend you want) to run one of the [Google Cloud Storage server SDKs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to set the file as public.  (You will probably also want some way to authorize that the user calling your API should be able to make this change.)

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that. Not a huge deal, just a pain in the but on what seems like something that should be supported in the firebase API.

Comment: You are always welcome to file a feature request.  Though it's worth noting that download URLs are the provided mechanism for providing public URLs.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I would use the downloadURL() if it was compatible with other services...such as the Google Doc Viewer. But for better/worse a lot of Doc/File viewers expect the url to contain the extension at end of URL and firebase doesn't support this.  A quick suggestion for firebase team, maybe construct the URL so token is at start of the URL and end with filename/extesion.

Comment: If you want the Firebase team to see a suggestion, use the link to Firebase support that I provided in the prior comment.